# AngularJS Attribute Directive. Not compile value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I have Angular directive for attribute title.

```
.directive('titleDate', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            datetime: '=titleDate'
        },

        link: function($scope, element) {
            element.attr('title','{{ '+$scope.datetime+' | amDateFormat: \'D MMMM HH:mm\' }}');             
        }
    }
});
```

Directive add title for component. But title return string expression like:

```
{{ 21.04.2014:15.20.22 | amDateFormat: 'D MMMM HH:mm' }}
```

So filter not apply. How compile this string or that i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to use filter in a directive is to inject $filter service:

```
$filter('amDateFormat')($scope.datetime, 'D MMMM HH:mm');
```

So your code would look like:

```
.directive('titleDate', ['$filter', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            datetime: '=titleDate'
        },

        link: function($scope, element) {
            element.attr('title', $filter('amDateFormat')($scope.datetime, 'D MMMM HH:mm'));             
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the date 21.04.2014:15.20.22 should be inside quotes in the expression like '21.04.2014:15.20.22'

Comment: element.attr('title','{{ \''+$scope.datetime+'\' | amDateFormat: \'D MMMM HH:mm\' }}');  not help!

Comment: I would guess that in the titleDate attribute of the directive you would want @ (one-way) binding just to get a value there (<div title-date="{{2 | currency}}"></div>) (I used the currency filter because i don't have moment library available) and then in the directive you should have elem.attr('title', $scope.datetime). it should then bind correct